# Zend 2 Framework Multiple Databases

Tags: php, database, zend-framework2

I trying to configure several database connection in my global.php file. I followed this tutorial ( https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/zend-framework-2-multiple-named-db-adapter-instances-using-adapters-subkey/#comments ) and was able to access the databases over the servicemanager

Now it looks like

```
    //config/autoload/global.php
return array(
    'db' => array(
        //this is for primary adapter....
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'             => 'mysql:dbname=zf21_learn;host=localhost',
        'driver_options'  => array(
             PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
         ),

        //other adapter when it needed...
        'adapters' => array(

            'db1' => array(
               'driver'         => 'Pdo',
               'dsn'             => 'mysql:dbname=zf2_staging;host=localhost',
               'driver_options'  => array(
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
                ),
            ),
            'db2' => array(
               'driver'         => 'Pdo',
               'dsn'             => 'mysql:dbname=zf2_test;host=localhost',
               'driver_options'  => array(
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
                ),
            ),

        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        // for primary db adapter that called
        // by $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                    => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
        // to allow other adapter to be called by
        // $sm->get('db1') or $sm->get('db2') based on the adapters config.
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Now i can access the primary db by $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
and db1 by $sm->get('db1') in the controller.

Now my question : Is it possible to load all adapters in a array so i can loop through them and pic the one i need.

Comment: Why would you load them in an array, when you have them loaded in SM?